# Xcode linker command failed issue

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, linker

```
Ld /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-    aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Products/Debug/NBAPlayer normal x86_64
    cd /Users/noahheath/Documents/NBAPlayer
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NBAPlayer.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NBAPlayer_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Products/Debug/NBAPlayer

duplicate symbol __ZN9NFLplayerC1Ev in:
    /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UnsortedStruct.o
    /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9NFLplayerC2Ev in:
    /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UnsortedStruct.o
    /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9NFLplayer8ComparedES_ in:
    /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UnsortedStruct.o
    /Users/noahheath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NBAPlayer-aeoygjukxhrzaxddvctkqcefsiql/Build/Intermediates/NBAPlayer.build/Debug/NBAPlayer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the script I have received from xcode and I cannot find the error to save my life. Can someone help me debug this? Forgive me if this isn't presented in the correct format. This is my first time using this website.

Here is my main code and here is the unsorted struct class

```
#include "NFL.h"
class UnsortedStruct
{
public:
    UnsortedStruct();
    int GetLength() const;
    bool IsFull() const;
    void EmptyList();
    void InsertItem(NFLplayer nflplayers);
    void DeleteItem(NFLplayer nflplayers);
    void ResetList();
    NFLplayer GetItem(NFLplayer nflPlayers, bool& found);
    NFLplayer GetNextItem();
private:
    int length;
    int currentPos;
    NFLplayer NFLlist[MAX_PLAYERS];
};

#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_PLAYERS = 10;
enum RelationType1 {LESS1, GREATER1, EQUAL1};

struct NFLplayer//describes the set of information for a NFL player.
{
    string position, school, name, team;
    RelationType1 Compared(NFLplayer);
    NFLplayer();
};

NFLplayer::NFLplayer()
{
    position=" ";
    school=" ";
    name=" ";
    team=" ";
}
RelationType1 NFLplayer::Compared(NFLplayer players)
{
    if(name < players.name)
        return LESS1;
    else if(name > players.name)
        return GREATER1;
    else
        return EQUAL1;
}
```

Comment: You have a duplicate symbol error, which basically means you declared the same object in multiple places. Please add your code samples (from main / UnsortedStruct) where "player" is declared. Short code snippets if possible.

Comment: @MichaelCMS I have added my client code and my UnsortedStruct file

Comment: The problem might be in NFL.h . Did you make sure to include it only once (pragma once / ifndef method) ? Did you implement / declared anything inside NFL.h besides function prototypes and external / class variables ?

Comment: @MichaelCMS yes I declared an enumerated type(I have replaced my main code with the NFl.h file) and defined it. I think I may have a misunderstand of what exactly you can do with a header file so the functions I defined may be causing the error.

Comment: Possible causes I can think of: the implementation of the `NFL` members are in "NFL.h" *but not inlined*, or you have included a ".cpp" file somewhere.

Comment: @molbdnilo removing the constructor reduced it to 1 duplicate, but I can't seem to find that one.

Comment: Posted an answer. Remove both constructor and the Compared function implementation. Rule of thumb : always implement body of functions inside a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your constructor and your Compared function inside the .h file. Move them into a .cpp file and things should run smoothly.

A more insight on what's happening :

.h files are copy pasted into every object that is being compiled . So the  main.o and UnsortedStruct.o will have the header file copy-pasted inside their object at preprocessor time.

You have two objects, and in each object you define the ::Compared and ::NFLPlayer functions implementation. You end up with two implementations of the same function, hence the duplicate symbol.

The .h files are meant to provide definitions for to-be-used structures, classes, functions (it's a forward declaration so to speak).

Implementation bodies are implemented in .cpp files , which in turn will be compiled then linked throughout the code after compilation.

When you see implementations in .h files, you will see that these are inside the class definition :

```
Class A
{
   void foo() { // do something };
}
```

This is valid, because that function will become inlined.

However, declaring void foo ,then implementing it as A::foo() in the same file will be troublesome if the file is included as header in multiple compile units (objects).

Comment: Thanks. I understand what was happening now. I redesigned that portion of my program and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of errors from derived data, I assume you did an upgrade of Xcode?

Do the following steps in Xcode:

- Product --> (hold down Alt key) --> Clean Build Folder
- Product --> Clean Project
- Window --> Organizer --> Delete derived data

Then build your project again.

Comment: I didn't upgrade xcode. I have gone back and added two files from my code to give perspective of what I have going on.